he begins to feel that the way he had lived was not good after all

The very rich man never walks; he always goes in a carriage. But in the course of years, he wakes up one day paralyzed all over. Then he begins to feel that the way he had lived was not good after all. No man can walk for me.

why did the speaker use the past perfect tense when the story is in the present tense and there was no past time he mentioned?
I think it should be "Then he begins to feel the way he has lived was not good after all."

Does this answer your question? Past simple, past perfect

@Lambie this doesn't answer my question. It is easy to know the difference between past simple and past perfect. but in my question, I wanted to know how we can use past perfect without even past reference. so

Then he begins to feel [in the present] that the way he had lived [precedes] was [the simple past: was]  not good after all. The past prefect always precedes another verb in the past, either expressly or implied.


Then he begins to feel that the way he had lived was not good after all.

It was obvious that the time after the paralysis was not good.  The writer hence felt that unnecessary to mention and instead included only up till the time before the paralysis.

The past perfect ("the way he had lived") frames his way of life as that of a former phase of his life. It was the life that he was living before he comes to understand that the way he had chosen was "not good after all".  It was his way of living before the epiphany occasioned by his sudden paralysis.
Had he known then what he knows now —that one day he would be unable to walk— he would have taken fewer carriages.

Using "had" here emphasises that the man has reached a turning point in his life: it puts "the way he had lived" firmly in the past, strongly implying that he sees that time as a different era of his life - and one that he regrets (at least, he regrets aspects of it).
Had the author used "has" ("... the way he has lived ..."), that would keep that part of his life in the continuous present - implying that the realization is insufficient to change his behavior or cause him to regret the way he lived before. That is: using "has" continues that way of living into the continuous present rather than implying a separation of the life before and the life "now".
"Had" implies that the man will change his way of life - or would if he could; "has" doesn't carry that implication, instead implying (weakly) that he may lament his circumstances but won't change his way of living (at least, not yet).
